# Find Fourier series of Indicator function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

> Find Fourier series of $f(x)$:
>   $$
> f(x)=\begin{cases}
> 1,\ \ a\leqslant x\leqslant b\\
> 0\ \ \ \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases};\ \ \ \ \ [a,b]\in[-\pi;\pi]
> $$

Here is my attempt:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&f(x)\sim a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(a_n\cos nx+b_n\sin nx\right)=S(x)\\
&a_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_a^b 1\cdot dx=\frac{b-a}{2\pi}\\
&a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_a^b\cos nx dx=\frac{1}{\pi n}(\sin bn-\sin an)\\
&b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int\limits_a^b\sin nx dx=\frac{1}{\pi n}(\cos an-\cos bn)\\
&\Rightarrow S(x)=\frac{b-a}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}((\sin bn-\sin an)\cos nx+(\cos an-\cos bn)\sin nx)=\\
&=\frac{b-a}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}(\sin(n(b-x))-\sin(n(a-x)))
\end{aligned}
$$
The question is can I simplify it even more? Or should my last expression be the final answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin(A) - \sin(B) = 2 \sin(A/2 - B/2) \cos(A/2 + B/2)$$

$A = nb - nx$ and
$B = na - nx$
$$A/2 - B/2 = \left( n \frac{b-a}{2} \right)$$
$$A/2 + B/2 = \left( n x \right)$$
Would be a more dense writing.